# Custom Camera using AVFoundation terminating app error - SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, camera

I am trying to make a custom camera in Swift 4, Xcode 9 with AVFoundation and I've written all the code to make it so that the `previewLayer` of the app displays and you can capture a photo but when I run it nothing happens and I get a Terminating app error:

> 2018-08-10 09:06:31.160691+0200 Yubi[313:12221] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key previewView.'

Here is the code I've written. I only have 1 `ViewController` for 1 storyboard with a capture button and a UIView for the `previewLayer`:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class CameraViewController: UIViewController {

    //This is the IBoutlet for the camera view (so the live feed of what u see)
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //To get a devie session and choose what side camera i think. In the Devicetypes: i am declaring what type of camera im looking for in the telephones devices (so functional pieces of hardware)
        let deviceSession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera,.builtInDualCamera,.builtInTelephotoCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)

        for device in (deviceSession.devices) {

            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {

                do {

                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)

                    if captureSession.canAddInput(input){
                        captureSession.addInput(input)

                        if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){
                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)

                            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                            previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait


                            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                            cameraView.addSubview(button)


                            previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height / 2)

                            previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame

                            captureSession.startRunning()

                        }
                    }


                } catch let avError {
                    print(avError)
                }

            }

        }


    }

    //if let cameraID = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.front).devices.first?.localizedName{
    //cameraID = "Front Camera"


    //This is for the actuall take photo button
    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {



    }

}
```

Comment: Check your outlet connection. There is one controller object which connected with "previewView" where it's not created in your controller. Remove that connection and try. It will work.

Comment: Is that solved?

Answer (score 1):

Check your outlet connection. There is one controller object which connected with "previewView" where it's not created in your controller. Remove that connection and try. It will work.

> You will see previewView with mobile type icon which mean that is not
>   declared in controller. Check attached image to remove that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you are using `previewView` somewhere. Check your ViewController's IBConnections in storyboard or XIB. There are possibilities that you may have connected `previewView` to some element. If you remove that your problem will get solved.